# finding the first non zero column in a matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

if i have matrix A like the following

```
2 0 0 0 0 0 
3 0 0 0 0 0
4 0 0 0 0 0
7 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

all the other columns are always zeros

I want to get the array B = [7 4 3 2]

how can i do that ?

Comment: Is there allways only one non zero element in a column? And what order do you need for the resulting array? inverted columns? sorted with biggest first? Are the elements allways in row 1?

Comment: you're example is very trivial, you could just do `B = A(fliplr(find(A)))` - but it will fail for a lot of cases. So if it doesn't work for you, post a more significant example.

Comment: yes only one non zero column @The Minion

Comment: @thewaywewalk it didnt work with me it only gives me one element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey this is the easiest code i can think of for getting all non zero elements:

```
test_matrix = [ 2, 0 , 0 ,0 ,0;...
    3, 0 , 0 ,0 ,0;...
    4, 0 , 0 ,0 ,0;...
    7, 0 , 0 ,0 ,0;...
    0, 0 , 0 ,0 ,0;...
    0, 0 , 0 ,0 ,0;...
    0, 0 , 0 ,0 ,0];

B = test_matrix(test_matrix ~= 0) %//rowwise non zeroelements
```

The output is a column we need to transpose it and then flip it. 
If you change the position of 4 to another slot in the column it will show at the end of output array B. If you want to have the last non zero element as first output you can transpose the Array:

```
B=fliplr(B'); %//fliping first to last and so in ( for the transpose array)
```

If you want the column ordered even if as said above the 4 is somewhere else in the array use the transposed matrix:

```
helper= test_matrix' %//(')transposing Matrix
C = helper(helper ~=0) %//Columnwise non zero-elements
```

If there are more than one nonzero element per column you must check if you want them rowwise or columnwise listed: Check B and C definition. Obviously C isn't inverse ordered just use

```
 C=fliplr(C); %%//flipping first to last and so on
```

hopefully that explains all questions you got. 

**Results:**

```
test_matrix = [ 2, 0 , 0 ,0 ,0;...
    3, 0 , 0 ,0 ,0;...
    0, 0 , 4 ,0 ,0;...
    7, 0 , 0 ,0 ,0;...
    0, 0 , 0 ,0 ,0;...
    0, 0 , 0 ,0 ,0;...
    0, 0 , 0 ,0 ,0];

helper= sum(test_matrix');
C = helper(helper ~=0);
B = test_matrix(test_matrix ~= 0);
```

Results in:

```
C= (7,4,3,2);
B= (4,7,3,2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the columns and use `find`. Let's take

```
M =
     0     0     1     0     0
     0     0     2     0     0
     0     0     3     0     0
     0     0     4     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
```

as our example-matrix.

```
for i = 1:size(M,2)
    ind = find(M(:,i));
    if ind
        found = ind;
        break;
    end
end
```

Will get you

```
found = 
    1
    2
    3
    4
```

Which you can flip with

```
found = found([end:-1:1])'
```

which will get you

```
found =
    4 3 2 1
```

Comment: Thanks. I found the solution in 2 lines only

Comment: @TravellingSalesWoman can you please post this two-line solution? Yhanks!

Comment: I already checked the right solution I used the two lines from there

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear, but this seems to do what you want (since all other columns are zeros):

```
flipud(nonzeros(A))
```